# Why does react-redux compare state with the identity (===) operator? Objects can't be compared that way

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, comparison, equality

I'm reading `react-redux`'s `Provider` component (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js)

There are two cases when they compare objects using the identity (===) operator. Why so? We can't compare objects in JS that way. What exactly is compared?

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.subscription.trySubscribe()

    // One
    if (this.previousState !== this.props.store.getState()) {
      this.state.subscription.notifyNestedSubs()
    }
  }


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Two
    if (this.props.store !== prevProps.store) {
      this.state.subscription.tryUnsubscribe()
      const subscription = new Subscription(this.props.store)
      subscription.onStateChange = this.notifySubscribers
      this.setState({ store: this.props.store, subscription })
    }
  }
```

Comment: You certainly can compare objects with `===`; it's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: @Pointy What exactly do you compare? Object reference? They are different. Number of properties? Their types and values may be different. I know I can put `===` between any instance in JS. But between two objects?

Comment: `Object reference? They are different` - Not always, that is the point. It compares references to check if it is the same object or not

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you absolutely can compare values that way.  You can compare *any* two values with `===` - it's just a check to see if they are references pointing to the same value in memory.

Specifically, those two checks are determining if the Redux store state has been immutably updated by creating a new reference (usually a new root object), and if the `store` prop has been updated to point to a different store instance.